# In Angular 2: How can I use an @Input to set a component's required attribute?

Tags: angular2-forms, custom-component

I have a custom component in Angular:

```
@Component({
selector: 'spring-input',
template: `
  <div class="group">
    <input class="spring-input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onBlur()">
  </div>
  `
})

export class SpringInputControl implements ControlValueAccessor{
   @Input() isrequired: boolean;
```

How can I setup the isrequired @Input for this component so that someone can set the input element's required attribute like this?

```
<spring-input name="testcomponent" [(ngModel)]="testcomponent" [isrequired]="true"></spring-input>
```

The HTML5 input element required attribute bugs out when I try setting it using curly braces {{required}}

Comment: What error are you getting? 
You can set the required via attribute binding, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2)
and [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#other-bindings) section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out.  If I setup my component like this:  @Input() isrequired: boolean = false;  and  [required]="isrequired".  I can set the required property by <spring-input name="crShipVia" [(ngModel)]="crShipVia" [isrequired]="true"></spring-input>