# Angular 2 component input without value

Tags: angular

I want to create a component that has attributes that need no value.  For example, instead of something like this: (which I have now)

```
<app-document [mode]="'edit'" ... ></app-document>
```

or

```
<app-document [editMode]="true" ... ></app-document>
```

I would rather have:

```
<app-document editMode ...></app-document>
```

So the component itself has to see whether the attribute **editMode** is present or not. This will look a lot cleaner when I have a lot of such attributes.  I haven't seen any documentation on how to do this. Is it doable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Material2](https://material.angular.io/) wrote the following method:

```
/** Coerces a data-bound value (typically a string) to a boolean. */
export function coerceBooleanProperty(value: any): boolean {
  return value != null && `${value}` !== 'false';
}
```

Write something like that in your `app-document` component:

```
private _editMode: boolean;
@Input()
get editMode() { return this._editMode; }
set editMode(value: any) { this._editMode = coerceBooleanProperty(value); }
```

Then:

```
editMode == true
<app-document editMode></app-document>

editMode == false
<app-document></app-document>
```

If you use Material2 you can simply import the method as follows:

```
import {coerceBooleanProperty} from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use boolean `@Input`s to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<app-document [editMode] ...></app-document>
```

TS:

```
export class AppDocumentComponent {
  @Input() editMode: boolean = true;
  // ...
}
```

Now you have a boolean which you can use to change your behavior.

**note for better understanding:**

The default value `true` kicks in, if there *is* a (valueless) attribute.
If there is none, `editMode` does not get the default value but a falsy undefined. (So, that is why this works).

Comment: I didn't think of that pattern but that's pretty clever.   If I'm not mistaken the value of editMode is the inverse (boolean not) of what is intuitive but I can live with that.  Something like @Input('editMode') notEditMode: boolean = true;. Caffeine and monkeys seem to go together pretty well I guess.

Comment: This far simpler approach should have far more votes.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that 
<app-document editMode ...></app-document>
results in editMode being false.

Comment: the problem also is that with @Input we need to use square brackets not really natural

Comment: " If there is none, editMode does not get the default value but a falsy undefined. (So, that is why this works)." This is not true, it will be true anyway