# Angular 12 component input without value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

This post is related to: [Angular 2 component input without value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990032/angular-2-component-input-without-value/46523651)

I would like to achieve a card component with an **Boolean** input attribute named `scrollable`.

1. `<card>...</card>` without the scrollable attribute results to `false` in the controller
2. `<card [scrollable]>...</card>` with only the scrollable attribute results to `true`

I've already tried the accepted solution in the linked post.

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ylsxzm?file=src/app/app.component.html

---

**Update**

To solve the issue, I just had to remove the square brackets from the Scrollable attribute.

**Forked Stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s6d8ag?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `card.component.ts` like this:

```js
export class CardComponent {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this._scrollable) this._scrollable = false;
    console.log(this._scrollable);
  }

  public _scrollable: boolean;
  @Input()
  get scrollable() {
    return this._scrollable;
  }

  set scrollable(value: any) {
    this._scrollable = this.coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  }

  coerceBooleanProperty(value: any): boolean {
    return value != null && `${value}` !== 'false';
  }
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```html
<card></card>                // _scrollable = false
<card scrollable></card>     // _scrollable = true
```

Note that you can use `scrollable` without the `[]` since it is a Boolean value, and it will default to `true`. You can also use it with `[]` but you would have to pass the expression (or component property) that will result to Boolean.

```html
<card [scrollable] = "false"></card>    // _scrollable = false
<card [scrollable] = "true"></card>     // _scrollable = true
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufahkz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Ok, my stackblitz example is working if I removing the square brackets from the scrollable attribute in the html template. Do you know why?

Comment: As stated in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2 square brackets are use to bind a value to a property.
It means using the square bracket without giving a value to the property won't work

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it now?