# Angular component attribute without value nor square brackets

Tags: angular, angular13

I need to add the **`isBold`** property to an Angular component

```
<child-component isBold />
```

Remark the following

- I prefer do *not* use square brackets [] around the property name if used as `true` flag (as in the code above, long version would be `isBold = true`).
- However I would like to be able to use it as an input property

  ```
  <child-component [isBold]="parentBooleanOrFunction" />
  ```

the code bellow breaks the first requirement

```
@Input() isBold: boolean = true
```

Is there a way, in Angular 13, to do it without writing additional helper functions?

I *note* I read the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990032/angular-2-component-input-without-value), but the selected solution needs additional code or Material usage I have not.

Comment: I dont understand  your first requirement.

Comment: @Antoniossss what exactly is not clear for you in the first requirement?

Comment: I would say it should work as intended.

Comment: you can use directive to get just that i guess

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, I would suggest creating your own `coercion` functions/types similar to the Angular CDK functions/types (If you don't need to add the `@angular/cdk` to your project dependencies), which are very easy to implement than creating a directive for each Input:

For example, the [Boolean Property](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.ts) from `@angular/cdk/coercion`:

```js
/**
 * Type describing the allowed values for a boolean input.
 * @docs-private
 */
export type BooleanInput = string | boolean | null | undefined;

/** Coerces a data-bound value (typically a string) to a boolean. */
export function coerceBooleanProperty(value: any): boolean {
  return value != null && `${value}` !== 'false';
}
```

Then you can use them directly in any component, like the following:

```js
@Input()
get isBold(): boolean {
  return this._isBold;
}
set isBold(isBold: BooleanInput) {
  this._isBold = coerceBooleanProperty(isBold);
}
private _isBold = false;
```

```html
<child-component isBold />
<child-component [isBold]="parentBooleanOrFunction" />
```

You can find the full list of Angular CDK `coercion` functions/types under `angular/components/src/cdk/coercion/`:
https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/cdk/coercion

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to use any helper functions/types, you can handle it like the following as mentioned in [Deprecated APIs and features at Angular 13](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#input-setter-coercion):

```js
@Input() get isBold(): boolean {
  return this._isBold;
}
set isBold(value: boolean | '') {
  this._isBold = value === '' || value;
}
private _isBold = false;
```

> When a getter/setter pair is being used for the input it may be desirable to let the setter accept a broader set of types than what is returned by the getter, for example when the setter first converts the input value. However, until TypeScript 4.3 a getter/setter pair was required to have identical types so this pattern could not be accurately declared.
>
> Since TypeScript 4.3 the limitation has been removed; setters can now
> accept a wider type than what is returned by the getter. This means
> that input coercion fields are no longer needed, as their effects can
> be achieved by widening the type of the setter.

Read more about "Input setter coercion" deprecation in Angular 13 here:
https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#input-setter-coercion

Comment: thanks, however, read the before last phrase in the OP

Comment: @serge I updated my answer, please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directive to do that but it will not work as an ordinary @Input

Working examople on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyadj6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fis-bold.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftesting%2Ftesting.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftesting%2Ftesting.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftesting%2Ftesting.component.css)

Create input directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[isBold]'
})
export class IsBoldDirective {

  @Input() isBold:boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.isBold!==false){
      this.isBold=true; // defaults to true
    }
  }
}
```

Inject it into the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testing.component.css']
})
export class TestingComponent {
  constructor(@Self() @Optional() private isBold:IsBoldDirective) { }
  get value(){
    return this.isBold?.isBold ?? true; // this 'true' is the default value if isBold is not there
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
Absence: <app-testing></app-testing>
Presence: <app-testing isBold></app-testing>
Set value: <app-testing [isBold]="false"></app-testing>
```

with result

```
Absence:

true
Presence:

true
Set value:

false
```

Comment: so, no way without a directive with such custom code? say I have a lot of properties like this... I will not write directive for each boolean the same code...

Comment: either that or [isBold]=true. I think that choice is obvious

Comment: there is a way to do [isBold] without = true as well, without directive

Comment: Sure, iv skipped that. You can take leverage of fact that isBold is almost the same the same as `[isBold]=""`

Comment: just [isBold] does not work?

Comment: what would be the difference between [isBold] and isBold then ??:)

Comment: But anyway, it works just fine. The trick is to add extra hadling for 'undefined' and emptyu string cases.