# Conditional ngModel in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a requirement, I need to bind phone number to ngModel only if it's present. My code is as follows:

```
<cd-input
  size="15"
  [(ngModel)]="phone_numbers[0].full_number"
  [reformat]="something"
  [format]="something"
  placeholder="(111) 222-3333">
</cd-input>
```

This works well if phone number is present, but if it's not I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'full_number' of undefined

So based on this SO post [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745752/2968762), I tried the following:

```
<cd-input
  size="15"
  [(ngModel)]="phone_numbers[0].length > 0 ? phone_numbers[0].full_number : null"
  [reformat]="something"
  [format]="something"
  placeholder="(111) 222-3333">
</cd-input>
```

But, this causes syntax error.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

One way to fix this is using `*ngIf` and repeating the set of code again. But, What should I do to do it inline, like a ternary condition check?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would do it like:

```
[ngModel]="phone_numbers && phone_numbers[0]?.full_number"
(ngModelChange)="phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0].full_number=$event"
```

Why?

`[(ngModel)]` is expanded to `[ngModel]` (Input) and `(ngModelChange)`(Output).

I passed

`phone_numbers && phone_numbers[0]?.full_number`

to input to ensure that we have `phone_numbers` property in our component class and it has at least one item. And i also use here safe navigation operator

When we type something in input `ngModelChange` handler is called and i do the same things here for checking `undefined` value unless i can't use safe navigation pipe in the assignment (`(ngModelChange)="phone_numbers && phone_numbers[0]?.full_number=$event"` won't work)

---

If you use webstorm and see `Must be lValue` error then see this answer:

- [Webstorm: What does "Must be lvalue" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649612/webstorm-what-does-must-be-lvalue-mean/54650457#answer-54650457)

Comment: This actually worked for me, but can you please add some explanation for me to understand?

Answer (score 10):

For such binding expressions you need to split the property and event binding like:

```ts
[ngModel]="phone_numbers[0]?.full_number" 
(ngModelChange)="phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0] ? phone_numbers[0].full_number=$event : null"
```

Comment: Is it `"phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0] ? phone_numbers[0].full_number=$event : null"` ???. I'm getting error like : Parser Error: Conditional expression phone_numbers[0]?.length ? phone_numbers[0].full_number=$event requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

Comment: I forgot the last piece at the end - fixed

Comment: If this doesn't work, try adding parens `(phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0]) ? ...`