# Webstorm: What does "Must be lvalue" mean

Tags: angular, webstorm

While writing my angular application, I got this "strange" error message:

[image: "Must be lvalue" Error]

The code runs perfectly fine and I couldn't find any documentation for this error message. What does it mean?

The code is from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144391/639035 which is an accepted answer with 15 up votes.

**Code:**

```
<input placeholder="TEST"
       [ngModel]="phone_numbers && phone_numbers[0]?.full_number"
       (ngModelChange)="phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0].full_number=$event">
```

**Error Message:**

> Must be lvalue
>
> Must be lvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how webstorm inspection by using JSAnnotator works.

Try creating simple js file with the following code:

```
let a,b;
a && b=1;
```

[image]

It would be better if that error would sound like:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

See also [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36186)

Webstorm warns us that this code is unusual case and we can be wrong with writting it, for example

```
if (a === 1 && b = 2) {
                 /\
   Seems it should be == or ===. 
   So it's easy to make such mistake like this
```

**How can we suppress this error?**

- rewrite code in the following way

---

```
(ngModelChange)="phone_numbers?.length ? phone_numbers[0]['full_number']=$event : null"
```

- supress JSAnnotator for the `input` element

---

```
<!--suppress JSAnnotator -->
<input placeholder="TEST"
       [ngModel]="phone_numbers && phone_numbers[0]?.full_number"
       (ngModelChange)="phone_numbers?.length && phone_numbers[0]['full_number']=$event">
```

Again, it's just a warning and it's up to you how to deal with it.

Comment: I guess version 2019.1 is not release, which will fix it. Great answer

Comment: In 2019.1, it shows `Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` warning for code like yours. You can try the [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/) build