# How to use conditional in [(ngModel )]

Tags: angular

```
       //working
       [ngModel]="bets.amount ? bets.amount : '' "

       //not working
       [(ngModel)]="bets.amount ? bets.amount : ''"
```

If I use [(ngModel)] will not work. how to make it work?

Comment: the answer is you can't, since its two way binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional ngModel in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144230/conditional-ngmodel-in-angular2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+ngmodel+conditional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best practice is the using of the **getter** and **setter** and you put the condition in the get or set as you want