# *ngIf Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that gets the file name.

This name is filled in an input, however the input background color is visible only when I insert a file and the file name information is filled there.

I want the background color to be visible when it has or doesn't have values.

It had this:

```
 <input * ngIf = "items.length> 0" type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "items [0] .filename" class = "form-control Input-Metadata">
```

I want this:

```
<input * ngIf = "items.length>= 0" type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "items [0] .filename" class = "form-control Input-Metadata">
```

When using this I get the following error: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined.

Can anyone help me?

**component.ts**

```
for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

        const item: any = {
          filename: event.target.files[index].name.split('.')[0],
          fileType: event.target.files[index].type.split("image/").join(""),
          fileSize: event.target.files[index].size,
        };

        this.filename = item.filename;
        this.fileType = item.fileType;
        this.fileSize = item.fileSize;
        this.items.push(item);

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          item.url = e.target.result;
          const image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result;
          image.onload = function () {
            item.sizeH = image.width;
            item.sizeV = image.height;
            self.sizeH = item.sizeH;
            self.sizeV = item.sizeV;
          };

        }
        formData.append('file', files[index]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
      }
```

Comment: Change items.length>=0 to items.length>0.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much sense: how could the field be populated with the file name of the first item if there is 0 item?

Comment: @SachinJagtap Well, so the background color does not appear to me when I have no information, I intend to have the condition greater than or equal to zero :(

Comment: What are the contents of `items`?

Comment: I want to display the color (design) when the list is empty or not...
It only shows if the list is> 0

Comment: Remove the `*ngIf` then

Comment: I get Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Comment: Sharing the content of `items` will help. Does it have any elements present in it?

Comment: I added the component with the function I use

Comment: Just `console.log(this.items)` after your processing logic; sharing your component doesn't really help here

Comment: Just add one more input like this  <input * ngIf = "!items || items.length === 0" type = "text" class = "form-control Input-Metadata">.

Comment: Basically the items, contains all the added files and their information. I tried to put everything in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<input * ngIf = "items.length>= 0" type = "text" [ngModel]="items && items[0]?.filename" (ngModelChange)="items?.length && items[0].filename=$event" class = "form-control Input-Metadata">
```

It's based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144391/11841198)

Comment: @HarryJames Oh I see, try `[(ngModel)] = "items.length > 0 ? items[0]?.filename : '' "` then.

Comment: I get this Unexpected token '=' at column 44 in [items.length > 0 ? items[0]?.filename : '' =$event]

Comment: I think we have to split two-way data binding into [ngModel] and (ngModelChange). I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Change your *ngIf condition like this

```
<input *ngIf = "items.length > 0" type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "items[0].filename" class = "form-control Input-Metadata">
```

Comment: Well, so the background color does not appear to me when I have no information, I intend to have the condition greater than or equal to zero :(

Comment: @HarryJames I'm not sure how background colors have anything to do with this, but if you want to access an item, the item must exist. So, make sure it exists: if the items array is empty, then add an element to it.

Comment: @JBNizet  That's it, I want to display the color (design) when the list is empty or not

Comment: Again, we have no idea what "color (design)" means. If you want this input to work, then there must be an item in the array. So, if there is none, add one. If you want something else, then clarify your question.

Comment: I added the component with the function I use