# (Unexpected behavior) Conditional two-way binding in Angular template [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

I have an unexpected behavior when I use two way binding in Angular dynamically,
something like `[(ngModel)]="condition ? propA : propB"`.

For more detail, in my `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  props = { a: 'this is a', b: 'this is b' };
  myCondition = 'a';
}
```

and my template:

```
<h2>props a: {{ props.a }} (type anything, last input will change)</h2>
<input #a [(ngModel)]="props.a" />
<hr>

<h2>props b: {{ props.b }}</h2>
<input #b [(ngModel)]="props.b" />
<hr>

<h2>last one (type anything, nothing happen)</h2>
<input #c [(ngModel)]="myCondition === 'a' ? props.a : props.b" />
```

I thought input#c should have updated `props.a` but nothing happens at all. However, type something into input#a triggers input#c changed :(

[image: My Caption]

Could anyone explain what is going on for me? Thanks.

Stackblitz for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emaszv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this kind of binding by expanding it like this :

```
[ngModel]="myCondition === 'a' ? props.a : props.b"
(ngModelChange)="myCondition === 'a' ? props.a=$event : props.b=$event"
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgttzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144230/conditional-ngmodel-in-angular2)

Comment: So my code was equivalent to 
```
[ngModel]='myCondition === "a" ? props.a : props.b'
(ngModelChange)='myCondition === "a" ? props.a : props.b'
```
Right?

Comment: Nope, you have to assign $event to props.a or b according to condition in `ngModelChange`.