# How to enable/disable Autocomplete component of Angular Material based on Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm not able to enable/disable the [autocomplete textfield component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) dynamically or otherwise.

I want the component to be disabled by default. And later on some user activity, like on click of a button this should enable the component.

I tried the following code but didnt work:

```
export class MyComponent {
  // this DIDN'T WORK
  opts:object={value: "", disabled: true};
  ctrl= new FormControl(this.opts);

  ngDoCheck(){  
    // this DIDN'T WORK
    // this could be ngOnChange, ngOnInit or button click event
    if(this.IsTextBoxEnabled){
      this.ctrl.enable();
    }else{
      this.ctrl.disable();
    }
  }
}
```

How to do this in Angular Material Autocomplete component?

**UPDATE:**
[Similar issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724438/angular2-removing-disabled-attribute-from-element) was also left unanswered. To which I responded with my answer.

Comment: both your attempts should work, please provide a plunker, or at least show us your template :)

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Without it, no one can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by doing this.

```
<input [attr.disabled]="IsTextBoxDisabled?'true':null">
```

Apparently I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2).