# Set attribute conditionally in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to set href attribute of element  depend on content of element from interpolation.

```
<div>
    <ul class="contactnav">
        <li *ngFor="let contactItem of contactItems" >
            <a class="{{ contactItem.iconBootStrap }}"  href=" {{ contactItem.contactForm.indexOf('@') }} !== -1? 'mailto:{{ contactItem.contactForm }}' : '#'" data-rel="external">
                {{ contactItem.contactForm }}
            </a>           
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How should I define condition in  element to set href for value if contactItem.contactForm includes @ otherwise set for value '#'?

Comment: `[href]="contactItem.contactForm.indexOf('@') !== -1? 'mailto: ' + contactItem.contactForm : '#'"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you ask for is setting a property, not an attribute.

You can use

```
[href]="contactItem.contactForm.indexOf('@') !== -1 ? 'mailto: ' + contactItem.contactForm : '#'"
```

For conditional attribute binding see [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752#36745752)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  <a class="{{ contactItem.iconBootStrap }}" [href]="contactItem.contactForm.indexOf('@') !== -1? 'mailto: ' + contactItem.contactForm : '#'" data-rel="external">
      {{ contactItem.contactForm }}
  </a>
```