# Is it possible to add an attribute to Angular host element without a value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do host binding to input element's readonly attribute so that it will only be added to the host element but won't have any value assigned to it. The way that they are supposed to be used. I know that HTML spec specifically say that assigning it any value will not have any difference as long as the attribute is present.

But still. Is it possible to somehow add an attribute without a value?

### What I tried

As attributes are *removed* when they're applied a `null` value I've done this trick:

```
@HostBinding('attr.readonly')
private _readonly: '' | null = null;
public get readonly() {
  return this._readonly !== null;
}
public set readonly(value: boolean) {
  this._readonly = value ? '' : null;
}
```

This will partially work because it will remove the `readonly` attribute from the host element when the value is `null`, but when the value is an empty string this will still result in `readonly=""`, which isn't what I'm trying to do. My desired output would just be `readonly` without any value being applied to it.

I also tried doing the same with `renderer.setAttribute` but it works the same.

**Is it possible then?**

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfznhv) to play around.

Comment: Binding null to attribute will remove it. please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2

Comment: @Nour Yeah I know... I formed that sentence a bit clumsily. I edited it a bit to clarify that `null` works as expected, but empty string still assigns a value to the attribute which is not what I want.

Comment: So you need to remove the attribute in case of empty string also ?

Comment: No. In case of empty string I want the result to be `readonly` and not `readonly=""`.

Comment: `readonly` and `readonly=""` are exactly the same (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attribute)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using `@HostBinding('attr.readonly')  readOnly = '';`

**Explanation:**

- Assigning `''` to attribute will only add the attribute without value.
- Assigning `null` to remove the attribute.
- Setting non-null value eg: `true` or `yes` with set the corresponding value on the 
  attribute.