# Disable radio buttons in reactive form based on function value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an input made up of radio buttons, but I want to disable some of them based on a function value (which depends on the component's input). If I try to do this, I get a warning about using `disabled` attribute in a reactive form.

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
  <p-radioButton [inputId]="option.id" name="option" [value]="option" formControlName="option" [disabled]="foo(option)"></p-radioButton>
  <label [for]="option.id">{{ option.name }}</label>
</div>
```

Using the warning's suggestion, I am supposed to use a FormControl and set its `disabled` to true/false, but I'm not sure I understand how I would be able to do this with my radio buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Input fields in reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840136/disable-input-fields-in-reactive-form)

Comment: Similar question here - [disable-a-radio-button-conditionally...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890608/disable-a-radio-button-conditionally-in-a-radio-button-group-inside-reactive-for). Appears there is an open issue at Angular for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `[attr.disabled]="foo(option)"`.

Also, if you prefer changing at the typescript code, there is a discussion about [Disable Input fields in reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840136/disable-input-fields-in-reactive-form) that I think maybe can help you.

Comment: does not work I'm afraid