# attr.disabled null or empty string is returning true

Tags: angular

I am trying to set an inputs disabled attribute to true if a property has a value, however what I am using now seems to be returning true if the property is null or an empty string.

```
[attr.disabled]="userForm.value.email? true: false"
```

Comment: I think this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752#36745752

Answer (score 1):

To get an bound attribute removed, the value needs to be `null` instead of `false`

```
[attr.disabled]="userForm.value.email? true: null"
```

Comment: `undefined` should work too, right ? (and actually I thought only undefined worked)

Comment: I haven't tried `undefined`, but I can imagine that it works as well.