# Binding required and attr.required are not working as expected when the value is false

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using **Angular** version **6.0.7**.

I have four `<input>` fields where the latest three is only required if the first one is provided. I'm trying to make it working by using `[attr.required]="<boolean here>"` and `[required]="<boolean here>"`, but the required attribute is not removed from the input when the binding value is false.

```
<div class="col">
    <h3 class="mb-3">Ensino superior</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ad-higher-education-institution">Nome da instituição</label>
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution"
        id="ad-higher-education-institution"
        name="ad-higher-education-institution"
        type="text"
        class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="ad-higher-education-city">Cidade</label>
        <input
          [(ngModel)]="client.academic_data.higher_education.city"
          [attr.required]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution && client.academic_data.higher_education.institution.length > 0"
          id="ad-higher-education-city"
          name="ad-higher-education-city"
          type="text"
          class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col form-group">
        <label for="ad-higher-education-state">Estado</label>
        <input
          [(ngModel)]="client.academic_data.higher_education.state"
          [attr.required]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution && client.academic_data.higher_education.institution.length > 0"
          id="ad-higher-education-state"
          name="ad-higher-education-state"
          type="text"
          class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ad-higher-education-course">Curso</label>
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="client.academic_data.higher_education.course"
        [attr.required]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution && client.academic_data.higher_education.institution.length > 0"
        id="ad-higher-education-course"
        name="ad-higher-education-course"
        type="text"
        class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ad-high-school-conclusion-year">Ano de conclusão</label>
      <input
        [(ngModel)]="client.academic_data.higher_education.conclusion_year"
        [attr.required]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution && client.academic_data.higher_education.institution.length > 0"
        id="ad-higher-education-conclusion-year"
        name="ad-higher-education-conclusion-year"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        mask="0*">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to remove the `required` attribute when the first input is not filled?

This is the input when the first is filled:

```
<input 
  class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" 
  id="ad-higher-education-city" name="ad-higher-education-city" type="text" ng-reflect-name="ad-higher-education-city" ng-reflect-model="" 
  required="true">
```

And this is the input when the first is NOT filled:

```
<input 
  class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" 
  id="ad-higher-education-city" name="ad-higher-education-city" type="text" ng-reflect-name="ad-higher-education-city" ng-reflect-model="" 
  required>
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752) - use a ternary expession such as `[attr.required]="(client.academic_data.higher_education.institution && client.academic_data.higher_education.institution.length > 0)? true : null"`

Comment: Thanks, @eric99!!! Using ternary expression with null works as expected. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you just need to use a ternary expression that returns null in the case of false.

```
[required]="client.academic_data.higher_education.institution ? true : null"
```

Returning null the required attribute will be excluded from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `[required]`, not `[attr.required]`.

Support for binding directly to `required` was added in [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11116) from a couple years ago.

Comment: I tried it now and the result is the same. The attribute is required is not removed.