# Angular How to add dynamically attribute by passing attribute name

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am wondering how to add dynamic attribute in Angular. By saying that I mean I need to pass the attribute name. something like this:

```
<button [attr.{{attrName}}]="isAllowedAttribute ? attrValue : null" >{{buttonTitle}}/button>
```

I already see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2)  but I wanna pass the attribute by `attrName`.

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you'll make your own attribute directive, you can do use that attribute as a custom attribute to do what ever you need it to do or to be. https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cqdya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, it can be improved obviously, but I guess this is what you require...

Answer (score 1):

You may use a directive to set your dynamic attributes.

Look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnjfrg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-attr.directive.ts to get a glimpse at how to use it.

You may use the directive like this:

```
  <p [dynamicAttr]="'color'" attrValue="red"></p>
```

and access the directive values like this:

```
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = el;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Dynamic attribute: ', this.dynamicAttr);
    this.element.nativeElement.style[this.dynamicAttr] = this.attrValue;
  }
```

You may use the hook according to your use case. I have just used `ngAfterViewInit` to set things up only once the view renders.

Answer (score 0):

Write a directive that takes the attribute name and value.

This one takes a "map" of attribute name values.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-add-dynamically-attribute-by-passing-attribute-n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html