# Toggling Angular's cdkDrag drag n drop by code

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using angular 7's Drag n Drop and I have placed it in a div:

```
<div class="myDiv" cdkDrag (dblclick)="toggleDraggable($event)">Div Content Here</div>
```

So what I need to do is that when I double click on this div above the cdkDrag toggles on and off.

Either disappearing or not. Just need to toggle the draggable.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could consider using conditional dynamic attributes of `[attr.cdkDrag]` based on some boolean expression. With `toggleDraggable()` inverting the value used by that expression as needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is `cdkDragDisabled` input.

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="isDisabled">
  Drag me around
</div>
```

And you can just change `isDisabled` variable.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5yksug?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.html).