# Use ngIf to conditionally add attribute to button

Tags: angular

I have a dialog Box which has some buttons an i can set the primary="true" to make it the default answer for the user. In my case the value for primarryButton is button1 and button2 and i want the have it set if it is primary="true" the other button will have nothing.

```
<div>
        <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onCancelAction()" >{{Button2}}</button>
        <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onConfirmAction()" >{{Button1}}</button>
</div>
```

so the ngif should say in the line for Button1

```
*ngIf="primaryButton==='button1'" then primary="true"
```

but not sure how to accomplish that

Comment: You could try setting the attribute with the value being the check itself, e.g. `<button primary="primaryButton==='button1'">{{Button1}}</button>`
This will give you true or false for that attribute.

Comment: i was thinking of that but the code does not like it when you have a primary="false" so it expects primary="true" or nothing which doesnt work in this case

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2, you can hide an attribute by setting its value to null, so to expand on the previous slice of code:

`<button [attr.primary]="primaryButton==='button1' ? true : null">{{Button1}}</button>`

Note that `attr.primary` must be wrapped in square brackets.

Comment: That does not produce the expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearly understand what u want to achieve try this:

```
  <kendo-dialog-actions>
      <div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="primaryButton == 'Button1'; then but1; else but2"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #but1>
              <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onCancelAction()">{{Button2}}</button>
              <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onConfirmAction()" primary="true" >{{Button1}}</button>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #but2>
              <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onCancelAction()" primary="true">{{Button2}}</button>
              <button class="button" kendoButton (click)="onConfirmAction()" >{{Button1}}</button>
          </ng-template>
      </div>
    </kendo-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is simple, i want only the button which is set in the primaryButton value to have the additional attribute primary="true" the one which is not set should have no attribute of primary at all

Comment: @NoSoup4you Like this ? Edited.

Comment: I modified your code to work the way i need it which it does, all other did not produce the required output

Comment: I'm glad i could help You.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding ngIf on custom primaryButton attribute on your element why don't you play with class itself.

If still you need attribute only then let me know.. I will update you as per your requirement then.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ngIf` at all here as already mentioned in the comments. In Angular, if you pass `null` to an [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding), it does not get rendered. So we can just add a ternary expression to the `primary` attribute using attribute binding and conditionally pass `true` or `null`.

```html
<kendo-dialog-actions>
    <div>
        <button class="button" [attr.primary]="primaryButton === 'Button1' ? true : null" kendoButton (click)="onConfirmAction()">{{Button1}}</button>
        <button class="button" [attr.primary]="primaryButton === 'Button2' ? true : null" kendoButton (click)="onCancelAction()">{{Button2}}</button>
    </div>
</kendo-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: This will result in `<button class="button" primary="true">`, and the OP was instead asking for it to be rendered as `<button class="button" primary>`.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in how to conditionally render **just the attribute**, without an associated value, you can do this:

`<my-component [attr.custom-attribute]="someCondition ? '' : null">`

The empty string will cause it to be rendered in the DOM without an associated value. The null value will tell Angular not to render it at all.