# How to only show id attribute in HTML element when the value is defined in Angular

Tags: angular, binding, attributes

There is this simple component. Some usages require an ID on the input field, others don't. I cannot find out how to leave out the id attribute entirely when the value is falsy. How can this be done?

This is what I have so now:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label [for]="id ? id : ''" class="col-5 col-form-label">{{ label | translate }}:</label>
  <div class="col-7">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" [id]="id ? id : ''"
        [value]="value">
  </div>
</div>
```

But this results in rendering it as

```
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" id="">
```

For null and undefined the text literally is null and undefined, so that is not working either.

I wish to void having to use *ngIf for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2

Comment: use null, not '': `id?id:null` :glups:: it's the same that the linked comment

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use `attr`. If you pass `null` to it, the attribute is removed from the HTML.

Your input element should look like this:

```html
<input [attr.id]="id || null" type="text" readonly class="form-control-sm form-control-plaintext" [value]="value">
```

This updated HTML uses the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) to check if `id` is "falsy". If this is the case, then `null` is passed and with the use of `[attr.id]` the `id` won't be rendered in the DOM (tested with Angular 14).
For more information about this topic, checkout the SO question mentioned by @user13258211: [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734)