# How to bind in angular conditionally in *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have html that looks something like this:

```
  <as-split unit="pixel" #mainViewSplit class="custom-gutter" direction="horizontal" gutterSize="2">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let splitItem of splitData">
      <as-split-area [id]="splitItem.id" *ngIf="(splitItem.isVisible$ | async)" 
      [order]="splitItem.order">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
      </as-split-area>
    </ng-container>
  </as-split>
```

This works fine for split items that have id. But some of them are undefined and then there shouldn't be id at all in html. But for items without id html looks like this:

```
id="undefined"
```

I also tried

```
[id]="splitItem.id ? splitItem.id : null"
```

because comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209120/how-to-only-show-id-attribute-in-html-element-when-the-value-is-defined-in-angul) question suggest to use null, but it doesn't work. It just results in

```
id="null"
```

How to set binding so that there won't be id in html at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [attr.id] in place of [id] if the value of splitItem.id is undefined the attribute id will not be added in the DOM

```html
<as-split-area
  [attr.id]="splitItem.id"
  *ngIf="splitItem.isVisible$ | async"
  [order]="splitItem.order"
>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="splitItem.template"></ng-container>
</as-split-area>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was actually used in a question linked to the question i linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **index** instead of **id** ?
so that instead of  **undefined** you will get a **number** in property [id].

Follow this:-

*ngFor="let splitItem of splitData; let i = index"

and then in your <as-split-area [id]="i">

Comment: Why would i want a random number there?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the id as an empty string if it is undefined. Like so

```
[id]="splitItem.id ? splitItem.id : ''"
```

Comment: I don't want empty string for id. i'm asking how to conditionally add it i.e. not add anything if it's not defined. Pls see the accepted answer.