# Angular: How to conditionaly add an attribute in the template after checking if a variable is defined?

Tags: angular

How to conditionaly add an attribute in the template after checking if a variable is defined?
I want to add an attribute with the variable value to an HTML tag, but this variable might not exist. How can I check that?

In the following example, myVariable might not be defined in the component and it will throw an error:

```
<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" title="myVariable ? myVariable : null"></i>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2)

Comment: You simply forgot to add the `[]` to the attribute for Angular binding.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. If the variable is not declared in the component, I am still getting "Identifier 'myVariable' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

Comment: https://ibb.co/RB640c3

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" [attr.title]="myVariable ? myVariable : null"></i>
```

Normally the attribute should disappear when the binding value is `null`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2rr8hk

Comment: "Identifier 'myVariable' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

Comment: Added stackblitz

Comment: Yes but I repeat. You DEFINED the myVariable in the component. Remove the myVariable: string = null; from the component and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the [] around your attribute name to make it bindable:
`<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" [title]="myVariable ? myVariable : ''"></i>`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. If the variable is not declared in the component, I am still getting "Identifier 'myVariable' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

Comment: By design, the property should at least be declared in your component controller with public visibility. This is typescript way of coding.