# How do we set a attribute in Angular?

Tags: angular, download, attributes

I have a routine that sets a list of links, some of them have the property of "isDownload". I cant figure out how to set something like this

`<a (display download attribute if the element contains the property of isDownload)> anchor info</a>`

I can do something like this:

`<a *ngIf="item.isDownload" .... download>anchor info</a>`

`<a *ngIf="!item.isDownload" ...>anchor info</a>`

however I would like to have it all in one line but I can't figure out how simply display "download" if a criteria is met. I know I can do something like `[download]={{"item.isDownload" ? true: false}}` but that just set the value of `"download"` to `true` or `false` and since it is the download property it will try to download a file rather than just ignore it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks @PetrAveryanov, I thought I had look "everywhere" for this but could not find it. I will set this as duplicate as soon as the system allows me to.