# Angular Conditional Atribute inside template

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

How can I give an HTML tag a conditional attribute which toggles depending on the state of a variable declared in the component file?
I tried to give it a go unsuccessfully:

```
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef {{new ? 'mat-sort-header' : ''}}   >
```

In this case using *ngIf or ng-template is not appropriate due to the *matHeaderCellDef reference.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try following methods to do it-

By Applying *ngIf directive

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef *ngIf="!new" >
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header *ngIf="new" >
```

By using attribute binding-

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.mat-sort-header]="new?'': null" >
```

Make sure "*new*" which I have taken from your example code is variable which stores the value of expression to decide whether it has to use mat-sort-header attribute or not.
One more tip you can't use new as variable name as its reserved keyword in javascript.